# GCM InternalServerError even though direct APNs push notification works for ionic project using phonegap-plugin-push

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-plugins

I have been attempting for the past few weeks to get push notifications working on iOS for an ionic project using phonegap-plugin-push version 1.5.3 and using GCM. Following the instructions found on Google and on the plugin specs I was able to make the plugin work for the android version of the project. 
The issue comes in when attempting to do the ios side. Currently, GCM replies with a 200 but an InternalServerError failure when sending the notification.

To troubleshoot:

1. Used a sample ios app (non-ionic) to test if certificates uploaded to GCM were correct. The push notification was successfully sent, was received, and was displayed by the app.
2. Tested directly using the APNS registration id that was logged from the push plugin. Correctly arrives and is displayed on the app.

To reproduce:

Tested using Google's specification at https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client#receive_messages_through_the_gcm_apns_interface

`https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA`

`{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "great match!",
    "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
    }
}`

Response:

`{
"multicast_id": 4863359655944227000
"success": 0
"failure": 1
"canonical_ids": 0
"results": 
   [{
      "error": "InternalServerError"
   }]
}`
 Would anyone happen to have an idea as to what may be causing the issue? Any help would be really appreciated!